# Implementating spell drawing/casting mechanism in Luau (Roblox)

Tags: neural-network, roblox, luau

I am coding a spell-casting system where you draw a symbol with your wand (mouse), and it can recognize said symbol.

There are two methods I believe might work; neural networking and an "invisible grid system"

The problem with the neural networking system is that It would be (likely) suboptimal in Roblox Luau, and not be able to match the performance nor speed I wish for. (Although, I may just be lacking in neural networking knowledge. Please let me know whether I should continue to try implementing it this way)

For the invisible grid system, I thought of converting the drawing into 1s and 0s (1 = drawn, 0 = blank), then seeing if it is similar to one of the symbols. I create the symbols by making a dictionary like:

```
local Symbol = { -- "Answer Key" shape, looks like a tilted square
   00100,
   01010,
   10001,
   01010,
   00100,
}
```

The problem is that user error will likely cause it to be inaccurate, like [this "spell"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYJ9u.png)'s blue boxes, showing user error/inaccuracy. I'm also sure that if I have multiple Symbols, comparing every value in every symbol will surely not be quick.

Do you know an algorithm that could help me do this? Or just some alternative way of doing this I am missing? Thank you for reading my post.

I'm sorry if the format on this is incorrect, this is my first stack-overflow post. I will gladly delete this post if it doesn't abide to one of the rules. ( Let me know if there are any tags I should add )

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach to solving this problem is to use a template matching algorithm. In this approach, you would create a "template" for each symbol that you want to recognize, which would be a grid of 1s and 0s similar to what you described in your question. Then, when the user draws a symbol, you would convert their drawing into a grid of 1s and 0s in the same way.

Next, you would compare the user's drawing to each of the templates using a similarity metric, such as the sum of absolute differences (SAD) or normalized cross-correlation (NCC). The template with the lowest SAD or highest NCC value would be considered the "best match" for the user's drawing, and therefore the recognized symbol.

There are a few advantages to using this approach:

It is relatively simple to implement, compared to a neural network.
It is fast, since you only need to compare the user's drawing to a small number of templates.
It can tolerate some user error, since the templates can be designed to be tolerant of slight variations in the user's drawing.
There are also some potential disadvantages to consider:

It may not be as accurate as a neural network, especially for complex or highly variable symbols.
The templates must be carefully designed to be representative of the expected variations in the user's drawings, which can be time-consuming.
Overall, whether this approach is suitable for your use case will depend on the specific requirements of your spell-casting system, including the number and complexity of the symbols you want to recognize, the accuracy and speed you need, and the resources (e.g. time, compute power) that are available to you.